# Why doesn't Burpsuite intercept the traffic of mobile application developed using Xamarin?

Tags: android, ios, testing, xamarin, traffic

In an ideal case scenario, Burpsuite intercept the traffic of the application.

Application developed using Xamarin are working when we set up the proxy but doesn't allow to intercept the traffic ?

Answer (score 0):

I ve verified that xamarin app and azure mobile client does not use at all any proxy configured in android and ios settings !

Comment: I use DelegatingHandler in MobileServiceClient to intercept all header and body messages

Comment: It again requires code level changes. Is there any tool using which we can intercept ?